# Adding columns to existing php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

Using PHP let's assume that I have successfully read a record from a MySQL table using the fetch_object method and I am holding the row data in a variable call $output:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
   $output[] = $row;
}
```

If I wanted to add two additional fields: "cls" and "parentID" to $output as if they were apart of $row, how would I accomplish this?  Thanks!

Comment: If the SQL is easily manipulated, you could write static declarations in the SELECT clause without needing to make iterated declarations in PHP.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Loop through the array by reference and add what you want after the while loop:

```
foreach( $output as &$row) {
    $row->cls = 0;
    $row->parentID = 1;
}
```

You can also do this within the while loop:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $row->cls = 0;
    $row->parentID = 1;
    $output[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks nickb - as always a perfect solution.

Comment: Great solution, I'm using it and looking for a way to for example get the data of $output[0]->parentID, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: What if I get the following error: `Attempt to assign property 'cls' of non-object`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you changed the code snippet in your question, try this instead now (updated version):

```
while(...) {
   $row->cls = ...;
   $row->parentID = ...;
   $output[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: `$output` is a multidimensional array, so `$output['cls']` won't work correctly. And I believe the OP is dealing with an array of objects (hence the `fetch_object()` call), so `[]` notation will also fail.

Comment: If I json_encode(), it places the fields outside of the row data array:

Comment: Well, you didn't have `$output[]` in your question when I wrote this. You'd have to add the new data to $row BEFORE you assign it to $output, then. Fixed the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$myArray=array_merge($myArray,$myAddArray);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

or use array_push()

apply it in the foreach/while loop for each row.